# How to debug long scripts in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a page which has a `script` tag. The script inside that tag is very long, but I would like to debug it. Unfortunately, I cannot scroll to the relevant place in the Console, because after a certain length the script is simply not displayed, see the attachment:

[image]

As you can see, it ends with

```
return !filt...
```

The actual function looks like this:

```
            this.validate = function(filters) {
                for (var filter in filters) {
                    if (!innerValidation(filters[filter].filterType, filters[filter].evaluatedValue, data[filters[filter].key])) {
                        return filters[filter].isOr;
                    }
                }
                return !filters[filter].isOr;
            };
```

Question: Why does Chrome truncate my script and how could that be changed?

Note, that I know I could load it from an external file, but I am actually interested to know the cause of this behavior.

Comment: in my console i can see full code, which version of chrome you have?

Comment: can you put it inside of a js file?

Comment: @DanielA.White, I can put it, but I am actually interested in the answer, as third-party script usage is not always an option. See the last sentence in the question.

Comment: @dest, how large is the script you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The display of the script is truncated but it still parses and runs the code correctly. You should be able to view the full code in the Sources tab under the relevant host and put breakpoints in there.

Comment: Found it! Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long script, it is best to make that into its own file instead. This will provide you with the best debugging experience.

The Elements panel truncates large scripts to help keep things fast and there is no way to undo this. Therefore, you would need to use some external debugging tools to try and get at this, but even then most of them work best with external script files as well.

Inline scripts should be very short if ever used. For any decent sized chunks of scripting, allocate that into its own file.

Comment: Garbee, we are not discussing the pros and cons of external files. We are discussing the situation when the script is already inside the page. You might want to debug a page which you are not developing to study how it works, for instance. As a result, the essence of your answer can be reduced to "This behavior is due to speeing up the loading of the console and it is not changeable". Do you have a source to point to to back your claim?

Comment: There is no public data about the reason for truncating. It may have originated in WebKit ages ago. Thinking from a maintainer's perspective, you need to think about what happens when someone does a 5k line inline script. You need to syntax highlight that and in case of style recalc in the panel, re-highlight on-the-fly. That is going to eat time unless you restrict the view to a reasonable extent.

Comment: I partially agree with you, particularly with your idea that dev tools should not be forced to load pages of that size, however, a flag to support full view as an option with false as its default value would be nice. As a matter of fact, the only alternative one currently has that I know about is to find the scripts in the sources tab of the dev tools, see the accepted answer. However, the UX while doing so is not the highest possible :)

Comment: Chrome's ideals are to *not* provide options unless there is an extremely good reason to do so. That way actual usage data drives the decisions made and not the wishes of thousands of people trying to do things in slightly-different ways. If we always did "simple flags" as it often gets put, we'd have hundreds of options and code pathways that no one could maintain effectively.

Comment: That's fair-enough :)